# sharing link to whatsappWeb is sending incomplete text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, whatsapp

Hi all hi have the following code to share a link into whatsapp web from my web site:

https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=http://www.myapp.com/goto.php?e=321AAA

but when I click on the link or button doesnt share the entire text only:

"http://www.myapp.com/goto.php?e"

but no the =321AAA

Already try with Jquery too.

```
$('#w2').click(function() {
    var str1= "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=http://www.myapp.com/goto.php?e=";                        
    var str3=str1.concat("<?php echo $_SESSION['linkEv'] . $_SESSION['PIN']; ?>");
    window.location =str3;
    console.log(str3);
});
```

in someway the link is not processing the "=" character i think.

Comment: Have you checked the php output? Remove the `window.location` so you can see the `console.log()` Also ensure you have `session_start()` before trying to `echo` the `SESSION[]` data. If you have already checked/done this then please update your question and explain what sort of debugging you have tried and show/explain the output of the debugging. Thank you.

Comment: I think you might need url encoding in this situation

Comment: @WalterdeJong can you tell me how?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me...

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['PIN'] = 6543;
    $_SESSION['linkEv'] = 'FooBar';
?>

<script>
    var url = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://example.com?param=';
    var pin = "<?php echo $_SESSION['linkEv'] . $_SESSION['PIN']; ?>";
    var combination = url.concat( pin );
    window.location = combination;
</script>
```

Comment: not working, remember I have to send the link to whatsapp and then as aparameter my link with a parameter. This is how it looks in the whatsapp window then : https://prnt.sc/gwqn3e

Comment: Edited my answer to include the specific whatsapp url, still works, the barcode gets generated correctly on the whatsapp website...